# Export ftable factors to html

Tags: r, html-table, factors

I have a table created from `ftable()`

```
structure(c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), .Dim = c(12L, 7L), class = "ftable", row.vars = list(
    ï..petal_size = c("large ", "small", "small "), stem_length = c("long", 
    "long ", "short", "short ")), col.vars = list(flow_color = c("blue", 
"green", "indigo ", "orange", "red  ", "violet", "yellow")))
```

I would like to export it using `htmlTable`, but when I use `htmlTable`on this i get this result with no factors and just numbers like in the picture here

[image]

How do I recover the factor names for the htmltable? Please note the final output should have the same number of rows and columns as the picture's output, but it needs to have the factor names on the rows and columns.

Answer (score 0):

I will convert it first to `data.frame` and the add the necessary tweaks to obtain the desired output:

```
tableToHtml <-structure(c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
            0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
            1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
            0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
            0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
            0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), .Dim = c(12L, 7L), class = "ftable", row.vars = list(
              ï..petal_size = c("large ", "small", "small "), stem_length = c("long", 
                                                                              "long ", "short", "short ")), col.vars = list(flow_color = c("blue", 
                                                                                                                                           "green", "indigo ", "orange", "red  ", "violet", "yellow")))

 library(htmlTable)

 htmlTable(as.data.frame(tableToHtml),rnames=F, header=rep("", length(colnames(as.data.frame(tableToHtml)))))
```

Comment: hmm I'm getting an extremely strange output here from copying and pasting this code. I'm trying to make the htmltable look just like the htmltable, but this seems to have just 3 columns with the first 2 being factors and the 3rd being some value

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood you, I get a table with four columns: petal_size stem_length flow_color and  Freq. It is not your desired output?

Comment: my output im trying to get is just exactly what the ftable is. If you run that you can see what it looks like. The problem is that the factors on the rows and columns named don't appear for the htmltable() function. Column should be flow_color. On the rows there should be petal_size and stem_length